# Create high quality, unique backlinks from keywords to improve SEO and search engine rankings

Tags: php, javascript, html, seo

I need some help to create Javascript or a PHP script for my HTML website. I would like to create high quality back-links to improve my search engine rankings. The basic idea is to create a bunch of links that contains the selected keywords and key terms in the anchor text and title, with the anchor text and title tag always being different.

I can create two loops and create these two different texts, but I also would like to sort the created links by similarity, as to make the most similar title-anchor links in first place, followed by dissimilar title-anchor links.

Is there any way to achieve this to help my SEO efforts?

Comment: I don't think JavaScript really is most appropriate for such a type of thing, especially since most search engine won't actually parse the JavaScript needed to make the links.

Comment: I see, but I just want to create those links and save as a text for use them later.

Comment: Oh - sorry, I must have misinterpreted the question.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Thank you for editing my question. It describes better my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite an interesting idea to work with different anchor text and title. I know that link has to be unique, so I think that is the reason, why you would like to create all variations. If you want to order the links that way you should use the `levenshtein` PHP function. This gives you the difference between to strings.

Finally here is the code to generate those backlinks for you SEO campaign:

```
<?php
$terms  = array('SEO','linkbuilding','online marketing','internet marketing',
                'search engine optimization','search engine marketing','search engine optimization service','google merketing','online advertising');
$links = array();

for($i = 0;$i < count($terms);$i++)
{
    for($j = 0;$j < count($terms);$j++)
    {
        if($i != $j)
        {
            $lev = levenshtein($terms[$i], $terms[$j]);
            $links[] = $lev."-"."<a href=\"#\" title=\"$terms[$i]\">$terms[$j]</a>";
        }
    }
}

usort($links, "strnatcmp");

for($i = 0;$i < count($links);$i++)
{
    $buff = explode("-", $links[$i]);
    $links[$i] = $buff[1];
    echo $links[$i]."<br/>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for that. It does exactly what I want.